# How to stop chrome responsive inspector from changing the zoom?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMwG7.png)
i am working on a project, the screen size i want to work on is 1366x920
the problem is when i set it to this size the zoom turn to 93% or other value

i change it back to 100% the size change to other than height changes to something else other than 920
i tried this solutions :

1. selecting "Restore to defaults" in the Toggle device toolbar menu.
2. selected "Desktop (touch)"
3. List item

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

4. turned off the "Auto-adjust zoom".

i saw an old post but never been answered correctly, or the answers didn't solve the problem for me
any idea how to fix it ?